# C# replace one TreeView with another

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am building a searchable TreeView (`treeView1`), which will remove any TreeNode that do not contain the search keyword. However, I would like to reset the tree back to its original structure on the click of a button. I am storing the original treeview in a variable before the search is performed.

```
TreeView originalTreeView = new TreeView();   
originalTreeView = treeView1;
```

I then perform the search, which is likely to remove some TreeNodes.

```
treeView1.searchTree(keyword);
```

Then, when I click the Reset button, I would like treeView1 to once again show the full originalTreeView, which is what I cannot figure out how to do.

```
private void resetBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     treeView1 = originalTreeView;
}
```

This code does nothing (the listener is OK). Is it possible to do something like this, or do I have to populate the tree all over again every time?

Comment: You need to create new TreeView and new nodes from existing nodes. A method can be written for the purpose. Also can you explain what is `keyword` here? What criteria you are using for search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code are assign the reference to `originalTreeView` only, but not copy/clone as a new object (backup).

Please try this [Copy all treeView parent and children to another treeView c# WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619763/copy-all-treeview-parent-and-childs-to-another-treeview-c-sharp-winforms)