# Copy special node of a treeview by giving the number of node to another treeview

Tags: c#, xml, treeview

I am new to `C#` and I want to do some projects. I have an `XML` file and I have created a `treeview` of this file. Then I wan to chose some nodes of the `treeview` under conduction and then build another tree.
In better words it is somehow an abstract from the current `treeview`. Of course it may happen I create an empty node as well. For `examlpe`:

```
TreeNodeCollection nodes;
foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
{
    if (something)
    {
         copy node(i) from treeview1 to treeview2
    }
    else
    {
         add empty node to treeview2
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate for your helps in advance!

Comment: you can traverse the tree
raed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619763/copy-all-treeview-parent-and-children-to-another-treeview-c-sharp-winforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? If not you need to describe your problem better.

```
TreeNodeCollection nodes;
foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
{
    if (something)
    {
         treeView2.Nodes.Add(node);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is somehow what I mean is getting access to a node by giving the number of node.

Comment: What have you tried? If find your question and comment unclear. Maybe edit it to make it more understandable? You can loop over the items in a for loop and get to them like this: `treeView1.Nodes[i]` for example `treeView2.Nodes.Add(treeView1.Nodes[i])`