# Redraw a treeview of a form in another form

Tags: c#, treeview

I have created a treeview in a form and I have another form that I want to redraw the treeview in it exactly. I used constructor to get my treeview in the second form but when I show the second form no treeview is displayed. 
It should be noted that when I a get a text of a label in the first form, I can display it in the second form exactly but I can not do that for treeview. In fact, I do not know which property of treeview should be used to display it?
Would you mind helping me?

Best

Comment: Always post the code in question.

Comment: When asking a question please be sure to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can easily see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can pass a child control to another parent, but to show it you need to add it to the controls collection and you also need to change the `Parent` property of the tree view:

```
public Form2(TreeView treeView)
    : this() // default constructor calls InitializeComponent();
{
    this.Controls.Add(treeView);
    treeView.Left = 100;
    treeView.Top = 100;
    treeView.Parent = this;
}
```

and the tree view will be shown.

**But there is a surprise for you.**

The tree view has now disappeared from the original form !!!!!.

Because this is how windows forms controls work.

So what you need to do is to have your own TreeView in your second form, and to copy all the values (nodes, by value, not by reference) and re-populate the tree view in your second form.

This post should help:

[Copy all treeView parent and children to another treeView c# WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619763/copy-all-treeview-parent-and-children-to-another-treeview-c-sharp-winforms)